# Having trouble extending ActiveStorage::Attachment with acts_as_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

Can someone offer best practices for adding acts_as_list to active storage attachments?  The gem requires "acts_as_list" added to the model in question.  I am hesitant to edit the ActiveStorage model in the gems directory but am new at extending ruby/rails.

All of this is about the coding hell I am in adding sorting to attached images!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it's not a good idea to extend the `ActiveStore` class as that will extend it for all your uses. I've seen a suggestion to keep an array of attachment id's (ordered) in the parent model. You could use a serialised column for this backed by `jsonb` or something like that.